# Database: SQL Pagination - How many pages?

Tags: sql, database, performance

I'm using MySQL LIMIT to display 50 rows (pages) at a time, like so:

```
SELECT cols
FROM table
LIMIT 49, 50
```

What's the most efficient way for me to determine how many "pages" I have in my result set (how many total records my query is producing)?

Before I run the code above, should I just run a quick and dirty:

```
SELECT COUNT(cols)
FROM table
```

to determine the # of rows in my result set?

(This seems kind of inefficient to run 2 queries to do this)

Comment: are you even trying to read on how to do things or just waiting for responses... Try querying on your question first, handful of responses already on this.

Comment: If I could have found what I thought was an answer, I wouldn't ask it.  Instead of deleting my post, why don't you post a link to the answer.

Comment: I don't mind if you delete the post, as long as you post a link to the answer and mark this question as a "duplicate"

Comment: If your query has no search criteria as shown, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table` is usually optimized and fast.  `SELECT COUNT(cols) FROM Table` is a different query; it counts the number of non-null values in the column 'cols'.  There isn't an alternative to counting unless you want to make estimates (as Google estimates the number of relevant results, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use FOUND_ROWS() function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score 0):

i think you are over optimizing. The only thing you can do to optimize the pagination process that i can think of is to keep the count in session, so you only do it once during page navigation, bad part it will be bad if new items are added during pagination.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (which might only work with some databases) is to peek inside the query plan to see what the optimizer is forecasting as a total row count. For example, in Oracle you can access the EXPLAIN plan and see that the optimizer estimates that, say, x rows are going to be returned in total. The accuracy of this of course depends on a number of factors: how appropriately the tables are indexed, how non-stale the statistics are etc.etc.